# If statement isn't taking my string values and evaluating them as a boolean (java beginner problems)

Tags: java, string, if-statement, boolean

//Program always prints the line written in the if statement. 
   //Also, eclipse returns an error every time I try to add an else statement

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Arrays;
public class Practice {

public static void main(String[] args)


Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Enter the number of artists you would like to search: ");
int number = input.nextInt();
String junk = input.nextLine();
String []artist = new String[number];

for(int i=0; i < number ; i++)
{
    artist[i]= input.nextLine();
}
System.out.println("Here is the list of artists you searched for: " + Arrays.toString(artist) + ". Is this correct?");

String check = input.nextLine();
if((check.equalsIgnoreCase("yes") || check.equalsIgnoreCase("y")) == false); //this continually returns both print statements in and out of the if statement even if I input something other than yes or y and I have no idea why
{
    System.out.println("Cool! Enjoy your search!"); //this always prints no matter what
} 

System.out.println("Please try again! Sorry for the inconvenience!"); //won't let me add an else statement
```

Comment: Geez. I've spent the past hour trying to figure this thing out and the culprit was a semi-colon. (and my lack of diligence)

Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 4):

You have a dangling `;` at the end of your condition

```
if((check.equalsIgnoreCase("yes") || check.equalsIgnoreCase("y")) == false) // ; was here
{

}
```

Remove it. This is known as an empty statement. You could rewrite it as

```
if((check.equalsIgnoreCase("yes") || check.equalsIgnoreCase("y")) == false)
    ; 

{
    System.out.println("Cool! Enjoy your search!"); //this always prints no matter what
}
```

Since a block `{ /* ... */ }` is valid code, it will get executed no matter what.

Answer (score 1):

Your "if-then" statement is being treated as a regular end statement since there is a semicolon ";" added before the scope of your "if-then" block "{ }" begins.

[Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/if.html) shows that before you start writing the body of the statement, use brackets

```
int choice = input.nextInt();  //How does the steak taste?

if(choice == 1) {
String Steak = "Amazing"
System.out.println(choice);
}
```

The variable "choice" ends with a semicolon and is now declared with a value that the user will input. Since the if-then statement is not finished after the header, brackets containing the body with further statements (each ending with a semicolon) can be executed.